# Can't make my trigger after insert working

Tags: sql, triggers, mariadb

I need to update column in table after inserting values.

I made trigger which after insert do that:

```
DELIMITER ;;

CREATE TRIGGER `work_ai` AFTER INSERT ON `work` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE work w SET w.time_sum = new.time_sum WHERE w.id = new.id;
END;;

DELIMITER ;
```

But can't get it working.. and I don't know what I'm doing wrong :/

Table schema is like that:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `work`;
CREATE TABLE `work` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `admin_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `task_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `client_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` enum('job','break','lunch') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'job',
  `from` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `to` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `comment` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `invoice` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `rate` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '800',
  `locked` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `time_sum` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `admin_id` (`admin_id`),
  KEY `task_id` (`task_id`),
  KEY `client_id` (`client_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `work_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`admin_id`) REFERENCES `admins` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `work_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`task_id`) REFERENCES `tasks` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `work_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`client_id`) REFERENCES `clients` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Sample data:
`to` = 2019-01-08 10:45:00
`from` = 2019-01-08 09:15:00
and result would be 01:30:00

Comment: Sample data added with desired result.

Comment: Don't be shy, add: a) `CREATE TABLE`s and `CREATE TRIGGER` full statements, b) Sample `INSERT`s.

Comment: I don't think that you need more info.. you can clearly see what I'm trying to do.. just have problem with that trigger in MariaDB

Answer (score 1):

So since `id` is the primary key, what you want to achieve is after inserting a row to table work, you want to update the time_sum value of the existing row with the same primary key in the same table with the time_sum value from the row just inserted ???

That is what the UPDATE statement in your trigger clearly says, but that just does not compute.  It's just a completely pointless no-op at best.

So pls give it a second try to explain what it is that you want/need.

Comment: You have page when you click on play button and it starts timer so u have `from` value but `to` value is NULL and `time_sum` is NULL too. When you stop timer you get `to` value and after that trigger should process and update value into `time_sum` because now he can calculated it (he has `from` and `to` value filled).

Comment: And how does "you have page and click on button" translate to database operations ?  If you want to understand trigger operation you need to know when an INSERT happens and when an UPDATE happens.  Putting together the bits and pieces you've given and a bit of educted guesses, "when timer stops" will give rise to an UPDATE and then ***of course*** your "INSERT" trigger won't fire.  (If it gives rise to a second INSERT then that will result in a key violation and ***of course*** then your trigger won't fire either.)  Extra tip : don't make this an UPDATE trigger.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.

```
BEGIN
    IF (NEW.to) THEN
       SET NEW.diff = TIMEDIFF(NEW.to,NEW.from);
    END IF;
END
```